# API to push action from a web application

Tags: apiendpoint

I would like to know what is the API which corresponds to this command:

cleos push action contract_name action_name'[param1,param2]' -p count@active

Exemple

command: cleos get info

API: http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info

Answer (score 1):

I think the API you are looking for is http://localhost:8080/v1/chain/push_transaction

Behind the scene `cleos push action contract_name action_name'[param1,param2]' -p count@active` construct a transaction and signs it with your private key. After that, the ready transaction becomes broadcasted to the chain